# Using mulch over cyclamen bulbs

Tags: planting, mulch, bulbs

I intend to plant cyclamen coum bulbs this fall. My plan is to lay hardware cloth over the bulbs to protect them from squirrels, and cover that with mulch. Cyclamen coum are very sensitive to planting depth, and prefer to be planted close to the surface (1/2 to 1 inch). Will the mulch suppress the cyclamen?

Comment: Tree seeds sprout well in wood chips, so I don't know why you would have a problem with it.